# Pen tool Scaling (Silverlight, Expression Blend)

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I have a custom shape which is drawn out by the pen tool.  For example, lets pretend I drew a trapezoid.  When you scale the object, the whole thing gets resized appropriately.

My question is: When I scale it width-wise, I only want the top and the bottom edges to expand.  I do not want the 'diagonal' edges to be changed.  What is the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the `Path` in `Objects and Timeline` and select `Group Into -> Grid`.  Then pick the `Path` again and change its `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`.  Now resizing the width of the `Grid` will not distort the `Path`.

Comment: Hmm That doesnt seem to change anything.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  But the point of this question would be: I want only specific legs of the Path to be effected by scaling.  Is this even possible without breaking up the path?

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  You only want to stretch the middle, the parallel lines.  No, I do not think that is not possible using just one `Path`.

Comment: Actually, a `Path` doesn't support that, but the Blend pen designer does.  Just multi-select vertices on the right hand size and move them with the left and right arrows.  Multi-select using 'Ctrl+Click".

Comment: yea thats what I thought.  Oh well, thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @Peanut: try multi-selecting plus the arrow keys; it does exactly what you want.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Right, I do realize you can multi-select vertices.  I guess I'm just looking for a way to make a nice custom button that auto-sizes appropriately.  For instance maybe have 2 of the same buttons, one with width 400 and another with width 200.  I'm just trying to allow for easy OO, where I don't really need to set anything once instantiated.

Comment: I see, you need three objects for that: the left, middle and right.  They seam together to look like one shape but only the middle stretches.